# RS256 jwt certificate not working on FeathersJS

Tags: feathersjs

I can't make FeathersJs work along RS256. I used the generator, but i receive 
`error: NotAuthenticated: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` when user logs in with correct JWT access token.

```
"authentication": {
    "secret": "whateverSecret",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "users",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "RS256", //set to RS256
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "auth0": {
      "clientID": "myClientid",
      "clientSecret": "myClientSecret",
      "successRedirect": "/",
      "domain": "myDomain.auth0.com",
      "scopes": [
        "profile"
      ]
    },
    "cookie": {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "feathers-jwt",
      "httpOnly": false,
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

and inside user.hooks.js is the default generator.

Answer (score 1):

The RS256 requires quite a bit more configuration to work. [This issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/400) mentions to make sure that your private key (`secret`) is a valid certificate and contains the proper newlines.

You will also likely have to [customize the JWT verifier](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/jwt.html#verifier) to pass the public key as the signing secret when verifying the JWT.